# Simple SQLAlchemy SubFactory example

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, factory-boy

I'm trying to implement `FactoryBoy` with a basic `SQLAlchemy` model over an existing database.  Below is a rough approximation of my setup, and the error rendered.

`Model.py`

```
base = declarative_base()

class Person(Base):
  person_id = Column(Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
  group_id = Column(ForeignKey(Group.group_id))


class Group(Base)
  group_id = Column(Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
```

`Factory.py`

```
class PersonFactory(SQLAlchemyModelFactory):
  group_id = factory.SubFactory(GroupFactory)

class GroupFactory(SQLAlchemyModelFactory):
  pass
```

`test.py`

```
PersonFactory.create()
```

Error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) can't adapt type 'Group' [SQL: 'INSERT INTO Person (group_id) VALUES (%(group_id)s,')] [parameters: {'group_id': }]

How do I correctly setup a model with `declarative_base()` and a foreign key relationship such that `FactoryBoy`'s `SubFactory` will correctly populate the dependent models?

Comment: To me it's clear that it is trying to assign the instance class to the raw table.  I'm just not really clear on what to do about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of assigning the `Group` instance to the foreign key column attribute, as you've noted yourself, create a [`relationship()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship) property that your factory populates:

```
class Person(Base):
    person_id = Column(Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    group_id = Column(ForeignKey(Group.group_id))
    group = relationship(Group)

...

class PersonFactory(SQLAlchemyModelFactory):
    group = factory.SubFactory(GroupFactory)
```

SQLAlchemy will then handle setting the foreign key correctly, when it flushes the objects to the DB.

Comment: Cool!  Will give this a shot today.

Comment: Just what I was looking for!